# Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

I know that there's already some post for this particular question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The error happens on this page : http://www.gentec-eo.com/products/thz-detectors, I can't reproduce it. I recieve an email that report this error 2 to 6 times a day, I've been looking for the solution for a while but I can't figure it out. One thing to notice is that it's **always from the same ip** : 72.14.199.4 witch I think is a google's bot. I don't get an innerexception. My code is pretty simple, the only thing that is different from the other pages is that I use Telerik's Grid to show the data with a jQuery post action.

Here's my error :

Message : Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

> Stack Trace : at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath
>   filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext
>   viewContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass14.b*_11()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) 
>   IP : 72.14.199.4

EDIT :
The inner exception

> Message : Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown.
>
> Stack Trace : at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception
>   e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   ASP.views_page_productcategory_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action
>   action) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath
>   filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride)

My view :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PageModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SPK.CMS.Domain.Model"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Web.ViewModels"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"><%= Model.CurrentCategory.HeadTitle %></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="additionnalHeadElement" runat="server">
    <meta name="description" lang="fr" content="<%= Model.CurrentCategory.MetaDescription %>" />
    <meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="<%= Model.CurrentCategory.MetaKeywords %>" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">

    <div id="splited-content">

        <div id="left-content">

            <% Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Shared.Views.MenuProduct); %>

      </div>

      <div id="right-content">

        <%if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CurrentCategory.HTMLContent)){ %>
            <div id="product-cat-content"><%= Model.CurrentCategory.HTMLContent %></div>
        <%} %>

        <div id="product-compare">

            <% if (Model.CurrentCategory.FriendlyUrl.Contains("thz-detectors"))
              { %>
                <%= Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductCompare>()
                        .Name("GridTHz")
                        .Columns(colums =>
                         {
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(Resource.MODEL).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.Action(MVC.Page.Product()) + "/<#=ProductName#>" + "/\" ><#=Name#></a>");
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Pmax).Title(Resource.Pmax).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<#=PmaxFormated#>");
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Pmin).Title(Resource.Pmin).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<#=PminFormated#>");
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Fmin).Title(Resource.Fmin).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<#=Fmin#> Hz");
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Fmax).Title(Resource.Fmax).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<#=Fmax#> Hz");
                             colums.Bound(c => c.AnalogOutput).Title(Resource.ANALOG_OUTPUT).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" });
                             colums.Bound(c => c.SensorType).Title(Resource.SENSOR_TYPE).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" });
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Surface).Title(Resource.APERTURE).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<#=Aperture#>");
                         })
                        .DataBinding(d => d.Ajax().Select("ListProductCompare", "Page", new { categoryName = Model.CurrentCategory.Name}))
                        .Sortable()
                %>    
            <%}%>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>

<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(g => g.DefaultPath("~/Content/javascript/2010.1.309")) %>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + document.location.protocol + '//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0010/6692.js"%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E'))</script>
</asp:Content>
```

My Controller'S action :

```
public virtual ActionResult ProductCategory(string productCategory)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productCategory)) return Home();
    var currentCategory = _productCatRepo.GetByUrl(productCategory);
    var pageModel = new PageModel();
    if (currentCategory == null)
    {
        return Page404();
    }
    pageModel.CurrentCategory = currentCategory;
    BuildMenusAndBreadCrumb(pageModel);
    GetHeader(pageModel, currentCategory);
    ViewData.Model = pageModel;

    return View();
}
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public virtual ActionResult ListProductCompare(string categoryName)
{

    var gridModel = new GridModel<ProductCompare>();
    gridModel.Data = _productCompareRepo.GetByCategory(categoryName);
    return View(gridModel);
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Edited 2 :

I have an other InnerException but I still can't figure out what's my problem.

> ```
> Message : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String 
>
> Stack Trace : at System.Number.StringToNumber(String
> ```
>
> str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo
>   info, Boolean parseDecimal) at
>   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s,
>   NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo
>   info) at
>   System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.get_MajorVersion()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper.get_MajorVersion()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions.HttpRequestBaseExtensions.CanCompress(HttpRequestBase
>   instance) at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ScriptRegistrar.WriteScriptSources(TextWriter
>   writer) at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ScriptRegistrar.Write(TextWriter
>   writer) at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ScriptRegistrar.Render()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ScriptRegistrarBuilder.ToString()
>   at System.Web.HttpWriter.Write(Object
>   obj) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.SwitchWriter.Write(Object
>   value) at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.Write(Object
>   value) at
>   ASP.views_page_productcategory_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) at
>   ASP.views_shared_site_master._*Render*_control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this stack trace doesn't help pinpoint the problem. I would recommend you logging the request url and parameters that were used to cause the exception. If you are using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) you already have this information and if not you could perform this easily in the `Application_Error` handler in `Global.asax`. This way you will be able to identify the exact cause and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've updated my reporting code so that I can have the inner exception, now I have to wait to recieve the exception... I'll post the full stack trace once I have it. Thx